# What does this OEIS entry mean by "Expansion of $(2x+3)/(x^3-x-1)$"?

Tags: polynomials

[Here](http://oeis.org/A078712) is the sequence on the OEIS.

The title of the entry is "Expansion of $(2x+3)/(x^3-x-1)$."

I tried polynomial long division between those two polynomials and got $2x^-2 + 3x^-3 + 2x^-4 + 5x^-5 + \ldots$ , and I do not see how that quotient can possibly mean the sequence that is listed on the OEIS $(-3, 1, -1, -2, 3, -4, 2, 1, -5, \ldots)$.

I've looked up what the expansion of polynomial division is, but all I find are explanations of how to actually do polynomial long division.

What does Ralph Stephan, the author of that OEIS entry, mean by "Expansion of $(2x+3)/(x^3-x-1)$"?

Comment: The OEIS is treating it as a power series.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't doing the long division correctly. I didn't know that you're supposed to divide the smallest powers instead of the largest powers when the numerator is of a smaller degree than that of the denominator. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{2x+3}{x^3-x-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty -(2x+3)(x-x^3)^n$$